# OpenCms 10 Content storing in the database

Tags: java, mysql, opencms

I am new to [OpenCms](http://www.opencms.org/). My Question is, if I create a template in OpenCms VFS (virtual file system) as a `JSP` file and add some contents like an image, text, link text, etc.:

1. where will that content stored in the MySQL database?
2. are all these contents stored in the same table, or in different tables?

Any idea appreciated.

Comment: If the answer below was helpful, please mark it as a solution by checking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the content is stored in the database, blobs (binary large objects) are stored in `CMS_CONTENTS` and `CMD_OFFLINE_CONTENTS`. The other tables are for metadata (i.e. `CMS_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES`, `CMS_ONLINE_PROPERTIES`).

   Difference between the OFFLINE and ONLINE/regular tables are for the mode: the term `OFFLINE` in context of OpenCms refers to the unpublished (authoring) sites, while `ONLINE` is the published site.
2. Actual content is stored in the tables mentioned under (1), while meta data is stored elsewhere.

Note that it is possible to configure OpenCms in a way that it exports certain file types as static content to the RFS (real file system), in order to deliver faster. But in any case, it's primarily stored in the database.